# Existence of a random index $K$ at which the infimum of $E_i$'s is attained

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have shown that if $E_i$ $(i\in I$, where I is finite or countably infinite index set) are independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda_i$ with finite sum, then $\inf_{i\in I}{E_i} \sim \operatorname{Exp}\left( \sum_i \lambda_i \right)$. I have also shown that this implies $P(E_k < \inf_{i \neq k}{E_i}) =\frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_i \lambda_i}$.

But I was further asked to show that this implies with probability 1 that there is a random index $K$ such that the infimum is attained at $K$, and $P(K=k) = \frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_i \lambda_i}$.

I do not see how to make such deduction, can someone help me please?

Comment: Is $I$ finite or infinite? If the latter, is $\sum{\lambda_i}$ finite?  I suspect you may need to show both of the following have probability $0$: (a) two or more of the $E_i$ are equal; (b) the infimum is $0$

Comment: @Henry added that to the question

Comment: @Henry Why from those statements the proof would follow?

Comment: *Hint.* One way of establishing the existence of $K$ is to give a definition for $K$. How would you define $K$? (You already know a condition that $K$ must satisfy!)

Comment: The $E_k < \inf_{i \neq k}{E_i}$ look disjoint events, so since $\sum_k \frac{\lambda_k}{\sum_i \lambda_i} =1$, then with probability $1$ exactly one of these events happens.  But that is not the case when $\sum_i \lambda_i =\infty$